# Pycharm - Git clone - "Unable to create destination directory"

Tags: git, pycharm

I'm trying to clone a Git repo using PyCharm, but it gives me this error event:

***Clone***
*Unable to create destination directory.*

The repo is being hosted on GitHub and clones to my C drive fine. But when I try to clone to a mapped network drive it gives me the error. I've tried running as admin and have done the regedit to allow elevated programs to view mapped network drives but haven't had any joy.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: My method for cloning is using the "Get from version control" on the PyCharm Welcome screen. It doesn't show an error message, it just flags an event on the welcome screen with the error message above.

Edit2: So I ran PyCharm from a cmd and have managed to get more detail on the error. This is the error message:

```
2020-04-30 18:40:56,561 [  41878]  ERROR - dea.ui.GitCloneDialogComponent - Unable to create destination directory
Details: Couldn't create destination directory<br/>Check your access rights
```

I can create files/folders in the specified location so I'm not sure how else I can alter permissions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! ,
*But when I try to clone to a mapped network drive it gives me the error.* Can you update the question with the command you used to clone and the error you got?

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question with your notes. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried cloning using a terminal ?

Comment: I ran PyCharm from a terminal and it came back with more details on the error. Its pointing to a permission error, but I have write permissions to the directory

Comment: Open CMD in administrator mode and try to run it again, do you still see the error?

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Try cloning directly with `git` in the terminal

Comment: This works fine. Must be a problem with how PyCharm is attempting to do it then.

Comment: Try asking it on [Pycharm Community](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm), you might get an answer there

Comment: I've also started to have issues with this, it used to work fine...

Have you been able to come up with anything?

Comment: I've also tried creating a project, rather than using git clone, and that works fine, as does running git clone from the terminal...this seems to be a bug in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the default suggested directory path, it removes the Repository/Folder name in the path. When you select a new path from folder tree, you loose the repository name in the path. Add it back at the end and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

It helped me to uninstall git completely from windows and then reinstall it back.
Like it's done here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1448JgLhCxU

UPD:
If you're on windows go to
control panel> All Control Panel Items> Programs and Features
There your git.version file should be located, right-click- uninstall.
After it, you can delete the git folder in the program files in the disk C. In my case, they were just deleted after right click on the folder and choosing the delete option.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30676338)

Comment: updated and added the instruction